# Cakephp not saving multilevel nested children

Tags: php, cakephp

I've been trying to save a record that has children and the children has children. I've tried passing a deep association, but I have only been able to save children on level 1 and seems like cake ignores children of children. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple but any help in pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Here is the sample array I've been trying to save:(Parent has many children, children has many children)

```
$data = [
    'item' => 'Item 1',
    'children' => ['Item' => 'Child Item 1', 'children' => ['Item' => 'Child Item 2']],
];
```

Model Association looks as follows:

```
    'hasMany' => [
        'children' => ['className' => 'ClassName', 'foreignKey' => 'parent_id', 'propertyName' => 'children', 'dependent' => true, 'cascadeCallbacks' => true],
    ]
    'belongsTo' => [
        'Parent' => ['className' => 'ClassName', 'foreignKey' => 'parent_id', 'propertyName' => 'Parent']
    ],
```

Save Method in the controller:

```
$items = $itemsTable->newEntities($data, [
    'associated' => ['children', 'children.children]
]);
$articles->save($items);
```

I am using CakePHP version: 4.4

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: My apologies, I've added the version to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just like patching, saving also only processes first level associations by default. In order to include deeper nested associations, you have to use the `associated` option for it too:

```php
$articles->save($items, ['associated' => 'children.children']);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations)**

Comment: I tried exactly what you're suggesting, as mentioned in the question as well. It seems to ignore 'children.children' and only saves the 1st level.